# Substrate NPoS Chain Elections Fail

Tags: substrate

Private NPoS chain using substrate, there are 4 validators, when 1 node goes down, subsequent elections keep on failing even if the node goes back online again. Is it normal behaviour?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because one one election fails, it needs to be recovered. There are generally two ways to do this:

[`submit_emergency_solution`](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/pallet_election_provider_multi_phase/pallet/enum.Call.html#variant.set_emergency_election_result), and [`governance_fallback`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/10663/files). The latter is much easier and is made exactly to help test-nets recover easier.

More context and info about why the election is failing should be same as [this question](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/651/substrate-validators-election-failing-and-connectivy-lost/676?noredirect=1#comment491_676).